# How to bind <a href>template in angular 2 dynamically?

Tags: angular

Please find the below code

Component.ts

```
getReply():string{if(condition){
return "The link is: <a href = 'https://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
}
```

I am binding the above in front end using [innerHtml], using which the above code gets binded and displaying the link, on click which directs to google site.

Whereas, when I try making it dynamically, the link is displayed but not directing to google site.Please find below the way I have tried,

Component.ts

```
export class ReplyComponent{
link : string;
    getReply():string{if(condition){
    this.link = "https://www.google.com";
        return "The link is: <a href = 'this.link'>Google</a>";
        }
}
```

On trying this, I am able to get the link, but it is not redirecting to google site. Please correct me if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: you used "this.link" as a string? try "The link is: <a href = " + this.link + ">Google</a>";

Comment: Using [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): \`The link is: <a href="${this.link}">Google</a>\`;

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your syntax. The return statement is all string.

```
return "The link is: <a href = 'this.link'>Google</a>";
```

Here the return statement will return it as a string. To acheive the dynamism change your return value as follows:

```
return "The link is: <a href = "+this.link+">Google</a>";
```

so that `this.link` is treated as variable and not as string.